# Meaning of the discrete Fourier transform in condensed matter

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, tight-binding

I'm in a CMP course now and I think I'm taking for granted what it means for a creation/annihilation operator to be Fourier transformed. I understand what a Fourier transform is for some *function*, but I'm not sure I could give a concrete definition of or justification for a Fourier transform of an *operator*. Please let me know how such a transform makes sense/is defined. Thanks!

Comment: Any linear combination of operators is well-defined.  A Fourier transform is just a sum of operators with some coefficients

Comment: Could you give a more specific description about your problem? What operator and what are the bases?